# How to pass additional variable into withCount() function in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to pass two more additional variables into ->withCount function.
But for some reason, I am getting an error about `Undefined variable`

This is my code:

```
    $date_from = Carbon::now()->subDays(1825);
    $date_to = Carbon::now()->subDays($days);

    return Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
                      ->withCount(["sellRecord as last_sale_date"  => function($query) {
                          $query->select(DB::raw("created_at"))
                                ->latest()
                                ->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
                                ->take(1);
                      }])
                      ->paginate(100);
```

And this is the error I am getting:

[image]

How can I pass additional variables into my withCount function query?

Comment: try ->withCount(["sellRecord as last_sale_date"  => function($query)use($date_from, $date_to) {
    $query->select(DB::raw("created_at"))
          ->latest()
          ->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
          ->take(1);
}]) this using use keyword to pass params

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I just need to add  `use ($date_from, $date_to)` to my code.

So, the whole code will look like this:

```
return Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
                          ->withCount(["sellRecord as last_sale_date"  => function($query) use ($date_from, $date_to){
                              $query->select(DB::raw("created_at"))
                                    ->latest()
                                    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
                                    ->take(1);
                          }])
                          ->paginate(100);
```